# OS X Snow Leopard in Virtual Box fails to boot after software update

Tags: boot, virtualbox, osx-snow-leopard, multi-boot, updates

I installed a copy of Snow Leopard on a virtual drive in a Windows 7 host. It has been working fairly well in the past few days. I decided to install the updates for OS X and now it is stuck at the gray Apple loading screen.

Is there a way to fix this? If not, how can I revert back?

Comment: Getting an updated version of the illegal (?) kernel will probably fix it.

Answer (score 2):

Installing and running OS X in a virtual machine requires a patched kernel. System update will replace that PC/Virtualbox bootable kernel with a stock OS X kernel from Apple. The kernel from Apple will only boot on Apple hardware.

FYi: Running OS X in a virtual machine or on any thing but a Mac is against the Apple OS X software license.

See this post here:

[Does Apple's license for OS X allow it to be virtualized on an hp pc?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/20965/does-apples-license-for-os-x-allow-it-to-be-virtualized-on-an-hp-pc)

And this post about the license:

[Where can I read the full lion eula?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/19939/where-can-i-read-the-full-lion-eula/19941#19941)